# find and replace special character " in multiple files using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

in particular path i need to find `""'` and replace it with `"'` in multiple files

Tried below code but its not working due to special character to be found and replaced

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.ini -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace """'", ""'" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: $configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.ini -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace """'", ""'" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}

Comment: 1) Put the code in your question and format it properly. 2) Why do you need to do this?

Comment: have nearly 200 files in a particular path which few mistakes in it and hence need to find and replace all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not escaping your characters properly:

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ini -Recurse
ForEach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    @(Get-Content -Path $file.FullName) -replace "`"{2}'", "`"'" |
        Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: Getting file being used error even in tried in different desktops

Comment: @user245596 Updated.  I forgot `Get-Content` annoyingly locks the file.